# how to fire timer when create the timer inside block function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

```
@interface Taxi_MainViewController : Taxi_BaseNavViewController
{
  __block NSTimer *timer_;
}



  [Taxi_do_order psg_place_orderWithMemberId:strMemberId_ orderStatus:K_orderStatus_open andCLLocationCoord:location.coordinate callback:^(NSInteger iOrderId){
        [Taxi_StatusView dismiss];
        if (iOrderId >=0)
        {
            isOrderExist = YES;
            [weakSelf_ showWaittingDriverAcceptView];
            timer_ =   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                                               target:weakSelf_
                                                             selector:@selector(actListen:)
                                                             userInfo:nil
                                                              repeats:YES];
        }else
            [weakSelf_ hideWaittingDriverAcceptView];
    }faile:^(){
        [Taxi_StatusView showLostNetWork];
    }];
```

when i call [timer_ invalidate],timer_ = nil; at other method, the timer function still call every 2 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the variable timer_ is never keep, and you lose the pointer
at the end block scope. With a property you have retain / release mechanism.

Try this :

```
@interface Taxi_MainViewController : Taxi_BaseNavViewController
{

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSTimer* timer;

@end



[Taxi_do_order psg_place_orderWithMemberId:strMemberId_ orderStatus:K_orderStatus_open andCLLocationCoord:location.coordinate callback:^(NSInteger iOrderId){
        [Taxi_StatusView dismiss];
        if (iOrderId >=0)
        {
            isOrderExist = YES;
            [weakSelf_ showWaittingDriverAcceptView];
            self.timer =   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                                               target:weakSelf_
                                                             selector:@selector(actListen:)
                                                             userInfo:nil
                                                              repeats:YES];
        }else
            [weakSelf_ hideWaittingDriverAcceptView];
    }faile:^(){
        [Taxi_StatusView showLostNetWork];
    }];
```